# gradle task tree exclude from build

Tags: gradle

I have the task tree below

[image]

can I get the doSomething task out of the main build task? for example, when I execute the `gradle build` command I don't want the doSomething task to execute.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1. Skip the task manually: `./gradlew build -x doSomething`
2. Reconfigure the `check` task to remove any references of `doSomething` task. You can refer to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:configuring_tasks for more details.

Comment: check {dependsOn= ['test']}